jQuery match element by id and class
I need to catch some elements in a form. The elements look like this:
<div id="wpforms-22603-field_17-container" class="wpforms-field wpforms-field-likert_scale" data-field-id="17">
<div id="wpforms-22603-field_18-container" class="wpforms-field wpforms-field-likert_scale" data-field-id="18">
<div id="wpforms-22603-field_19-container" class="wpforms-field wpforms-field-likert_scale" data-field-id="19">

The variable part is the number after -field_ and of course the data-field-id value itself.
So I wrote this:
var elem = $(this).closest('[id^=wpforms-'+this_form_id+'-field_][id$=-container]');

where this_form_id contains the value 22603. This works well, but I need to also specify a class in the matching process, and that class is wpforms-field-likert_scale.
So I tried this:
var elem = $(this).closest('[id^=wpforms-'+this_form_id+'-field_][id$=-container] .wpforms-field-likert_scale');

which doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Remove the space before the .
var elem = $(this)
  .closest(`[id^=wpforms-${this_form_id}-field_][id$=-container].wpforms-field-likert_scale`);

Alternatively use filter
var elem = $(this).closest('.wpforms-field-likert_scale')
  .filter(`[id^=wpforms-${this_form_id}-field_][id$=-container]`);



const this_form_id = '22603';
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var elem = $(this).closest('.wpforms-field-likert_scale')
    .filter(`[id^=wpforms-${this_form_id}-field_][id$=-container]`);
    console.log(elem.attr('id'))
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wpforms-22603-field_17-container" class="wpforms-field wpforms-field-likert_scale" data-field-id="17"><button>Click</button></div>
<div id="wpforms-22603-field_18-container" class="wpforms-field wpforms-field-likert_scale" data-field-id="18"><button>Click</button></div>
<div id="wpforms-22603-field_19-container" class="wpforms-field wpforms-field-likert_scale" data-field-id="19"><button>Click</button></div>




You can chain multiple finds with .end()
$cotainer
  .find("selector")
  .end()
  .find("selector")
  .end()



/*
wpforms-22603
-field_17
data-field-id="17"
wpforms-field-likert_scale
*/
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $matchMe = function ($cotainer, formId, fieldId) {
    return $cotainer
      .find("[id^='wpforms-" + formId + "']")
      .end()
      .find("[class*='-field_" + fieldId + "']")
      .end()
      .find('[data-field-id="' + fieldId + '"]')
      .end()
      .find(".wpforms-field-likert_scale")
      .end()
  }
  console.log($matchMe($("#container")).length)
})
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div
    id="wpforms-22603-field_17-container"
    class="wpforms-field wpforms-field-likert_scale"
    data-field-id="17"
  />
  <div
    id="wpforms-22603-field_18-container"
    class="wpforms-field wpforms-field-likert_scale"
    data-field-id="18"
  />
  <div
    id="wpforms-22603-field_19-container"
    class="wpforms-field wpforms-field-likert_scale"
    data-field-id="19"
  />
  <div
    id="wpforms-22603-field_19-container"
    class="wpforms-field wpforms-field-likert_scaleX"
    data-field-id="19"
  />
</div>




That is REALLY inefficient
